# Не работает функция изменения содержимого

Tags: javascript, php

Пытаюсь разобраться, почему не работает код.
По нажатию ничего не происходит:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_ACTION" value="save">
    <input type="hidden" name="_TOKEN" value="<?php echo $Token;?>">
   
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="<?php echo __('Name');?>" value="<?php echo $Listing['name'];?>" required="true">
    <div class="collection-footer">
     
        <a href="#" class="edit">Редактировать</a>
      
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Сохранить</button>
  
    <div class="row row-cols-md-6 row-cols-2">
        <?php foreach ($Collections as $Collection) {?>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="list-movie">
                <input class="d-none" name="post[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $Collection['id'];?>">
            
               
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

</form>
```

> 

```
    $(document).on('click', '.collection-edit .list-movie', function(e) {
    if ($(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
        $(this).removeClass("checked");
    } else {
        $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
        $(this).addClass("checked");
    }
    return false;
});
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {

    if ($('.collection-detail').hasClass('collection-edit')) {
        $(this).text('<?php echo __('Edit');?>');
    } else {
        $(this).text('<?php echo __('Cancel');?>');
    }
    $('.collection-detail').toggleClass('collection-edit');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ну так отладчик включи то..

Comment: зачем учить Jquery в 2021 году?? учите React или Vue. Не тратьте время зря. Вот, рассмотрите родмэп современного фронтовика, изучая только желтое - https://qirolab.com/posts/frontend-developer-roadmap-1602328125